# Json jackson : can't parse a json a file

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jackson

I m trying to parse a JSON file and store it in an list. I m getting this error : 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Here is my JSON file

```
{  "budgetList":[
    {
        "label":"Salary Tim",
        "category":"Monthly Income",  
        "real":1590,  
        "estimated":1590,  
        "date":"",  
        "month":"",  
        "year":"",  
        "type":"Income" 
    },  
    {
        "label":"Salary Tom",  
        "category":"Monthly Income",  
        "real":1540,  
        "estimated":1540,  
        "date":"",  
        "month":"",  
        "year":"",  
        "type":"Income"
    } 
 ]  
}
```

Here is my code
Budget :

```
public class Budget {
  private String label;
  private String category;
  private int real;
  private int estimated;
  private Date date;
  private int year;
  private String type;
  ....
  ....
```

}

My service :

```
List<Budget> budgets = objectMapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/json/new_exercise.json"), TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class,
                        Budget.class));
```

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

#### ANSWER FOUND

Code is

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Budget> budgets = null; 
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(new File("src/main/resources/json/new_exercise.json"));
            node = node.get("budgetList");
TypeReference<List<Budget>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Budget>>(){};
budgets = objectMapper.readValue(node.traverse(), typeRef);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jackson (GSON man, myself), but I'd imagine it's returning an object that has a child object (that is the lists). It's not just returning the lists themselves.

Comment: Hey, you should take the solution out of your question, post it as an answer, and then accept it. That way this will appear as a solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you, use GSON library? Is very simple

> Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new
>   FileInputStream("/opt/file.json"));
>   Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
>   List listBudget = gson.fromJson(reader, new
>   TypeToken>() {}.getType());

I think that the only problem is when Date and integer  parser when is empty. but you can register adapters like:

> ```
>   GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
>           gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
>       DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
>
>       public Date deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
>               throws JsonParseException {
>           try {
>               return df.parse(json.getAsString());
>           } catch (ParseException e) {
>               return null;
>           }
>       }
>   });
> ```
>
> Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new
>   FileInputStream("/opt/file.json"));
>   Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
>   List listBudget = gson.fromJson(reader, new
>   TypeToken>() {}.getType());

It works for you?, and dont forget to validate you json. "